# Modify file on EC2 via Cloudformation-Update stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have used Cloudformation template to create my EC2 instance. In this instance there is a file
in home directory that I copy from S3 while creating stack.

I have that file stored locally as well. Now, I modify that file locally and want to copy it to S3
and from S3 to EC2 instance.

I want to automate this process through Cloudformation. So that, whenever I modify this file locally,
after doing update stack, it uploads the modified file to S3 and from S3 to my EC2 instance. 
Can anyone please help how this can be achieved?

Comment: You just can't do that with CloudFormation. However, if you script your `update-stack` you could add a step where it also uploads your file to S3 at the same time. You will also need some way for the EC2 instance to pickup the new file from S3. It could poll periodically for a new file. This is pretty application specific stuff so there isn't really a standard solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to mind (bearing in mind the application specific nature of what you are trying to do) is using ECS instead of just EC2.

*Note: This may be overkill, but it would work. Also if updates were extremely frequent this would be a major pain so just uploading the file to S3 with a script alongside update-stack (if the update-stack is even necessary) and then polling for changes to that S3 file in your EC2 application would be fine.*

Anyway, this is a pattern we use when we are doing something like training a model with new data, which we then wish to deploy to AWS, replacing an application with an older version of the model.

You build the Docker image locally and your special file gets included inside the container. You push the Docker image to DockerHub or AWS ECS Registry or wherever. You update the cloudformation template ECS configuration to use the tag of this new Docker image and update the stack. Then ECS pulls this new image and the new Docker container(s) take the place of the old one(s) and it will have your special file inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I know of at least one way: set up your EC2 in an AutoScaling Group (ASG).  Then, on creation, use cfn-init on your UserData and have it fetch the file under sources. Use both Creation and Update policies.  On update, have the WillReplace attribute set to true under AutoScalingReplacingUpdate.  When you update, CloudFormation will create a new ASG with your fresh new file copy.  If you signal success on your update, it will remove the previous instance and ASG, giving you an immutable infrastructure setup.  Put everything behind a load balancer, and you got yourself a highly available blue/green deployment too.